# Angular Class not working

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to use classes in Angular to make my life easier but so far it isn't working yet. Below is my code and the error that I receive:

```
import { WizardData } from '../models/wizard-data';

export class WizardPage {
    private type: String;
    private data: WizardData;

    public getType(){
        return this.type;
    }

    public setType(type: String){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public getData(){
        return this.data;
    }

    public setData(data: WizardData){
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

and

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WizardPage } from '../../shared/models/wizard-page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-wizard-base',
  templateUrl: './wizard-base.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./wizard-base.component.scss']
})

export class WizardBaseComponent implements OnInit {
  wizardPage: WizardPage = new WizardPage();
  wizardPage.setType("address");

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

This gives an error on the line

```
wizardPage.setType("address");
```

Namely (CLI):

```
ERROR in src/app/wizard/wizard-base/wizard-base.component.ts(14,13): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/wizard/wizard-base/wizard-base.component.ts(14,22): error TS1003: Identifier expected.
```

And in Visual Studio Code:

```
[ts] Duplicate identifier 'wizardPage'.
[ts] Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'wizardPage' must be of type 'WizardPage', but here has type 'any'.
(property) WizardBaseComponent.wizardPage: WizardPage
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Thanks!

Comment: Ah thanks for pointing that out! Unfortunately, the same error persists...

Comment: @PankajParkar It actually does not have to be, javascript and typescript allow invocation of `new` without `()`

Comment: Don't write so much damn code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can declare members of class inside a class directly, but you can't access them directly. Basically you could access variable inside any method of a class, and it will belongs to `this`(context). Over here you should call `ngOnit` lifecycle hook.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.wizardPage.setType("address");
}
```

---

In terms of specify accessibility of variable in child or inherited class, you can use access specifier, that can be `public`, `protected`, `private`. These access specifiers works similar as that of how they in `OOP` language like `C#`, `Java`, etc. Thanks `@Florian` for heads up in comment.

Comment: @MikeD Glad to help you, Thanks :)

Comment: You can access to class members unless they're declared as `private` or `protected`. @MikeD : you should have a look at **encapsulation**, it's a core OOP mechanism.

Comment: @Florian spot  on. I updated my answer, thanks for heads up mate :)